# I know part of the value of a select option, I would like set that option with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to set an option in a select element based on the substring which will be contained in one of the option values. I have a solution but it seems quite convoluted to me.

I get the values of the options and put them in an array, loop through the values and check if the value includes a string I am looking for when it does I set that value as the select value. There must be an easier way!

I get the values of the options in the following way.

```js
// Get the select element where you can select a procinve with a pull-down
var provincePullDown = document.querySelector(".select-provincie");
// Array containing the values of the select options
var optArray = Array.from(provincePullDown.options);
var optArrayValues = [];
optArray.forEach(el => optArrayValues.push(el.value));
```

I then loop over the values looking with a likely substring.

```js
// Loop over the values in the select options
optArrayValues.forEach(function (el) {
  // Look for the option containing the right province
  if (el.includes(selectedProvince)) {
    // Set the selected option from the select element
    provincePullDown.value = el;
  }
});
```

The option values look something like this `sting (3)` and the substring like this `string`.

I would like to know if there is an easier way as to me this seems an overly convoluted solution. And keeping maintenance in mind I would like an clear solution that I will still easily understand in 6 months.

The page is created by Drupal so I also control what html is outputted and the option values are inserted in the Drupal template.
Let me also state that I am not a fan of jQuery even though the project does load jQuery by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) support any valid CSS selector, you can try with contains (`*=`) [`Attribute selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

**`[attr*=value]`**

> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value contains at least one occurrence of value within the string.

```js
var selectedProvince = 'province';
document.querySelector(".select-provincie option[value*='"+selectedProvince+"']").selected = true;
```

```html
<select class="select-provincie">
  <option value="prov-1">Province 1</option>
  <option value="prov-2">Province 2</option>
  <option value="province-test">Province 3</option>
  <option value="prov-3">Province 4</option>
</select>
```

You can also use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for cleaner syntax:

```js
var selectedProvince = 'province';
document.querySelector(`.select-provincie option[value*='${selectedProvince}']`).selected = true;
```

```html
<select class="select-provincie">
  <option value="prov-1">Province 1</option>
  <option value="prov-2">Province 2</option>
  <option value="province-test">Province 3</option>
  <option value="prov-3">Province 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I like it, it is very concise and not incredibly complicated! And it saves like 7 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly point to the option value if the regext is just a simple contain

```
const optToSelect = document.querySelector('option[value*=${SUBSTRING}]');
document.querySelector("select").selectedIndex = optToSelect.index;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain DOM methods with *find* and *includes*:

```js
function updateOther(source) {
  let value = source.value;
  let sel = document.querySelector('.select-provincie');
  sel.selectedIndex = [].find.call(sel.options, opt => opt.value.includes(value)).index;
}
```

```html
<select onchange='updateOther(this)'>
  <option value="1" selected>1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select class="select-provincie">
  <option value="province1" selected>Province 1</option>
  <option value="province2">Province 2</option>
  <option value="province3">Province 3</option>
  <option value="province4">Province 4</option>
</select>
```

But it's not fault tolerant: if a suitable value isn't found, it will throw an error (as do other answers). :-)

Comment: Nice I forgot al about the useful array methods like find, call is new to me. The weird thing to me is that these solutions don't cause a change event. I don't need there to be a change event but for some reason I was suspecting one

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery](https://jquery.com/) is interesting precisely when you want simplify solutions and ensure it is practical in terms of optimization. So I want to bring you a JQuery solution.

```js
var selectedProvince = 'province3';
$(".select-provincie > option").each((index, elem) => {
if (elem.value == selectedProvince) {$(elem).attr('selected', true)};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select_provincie">

<select class="select-provincie">
  <option value="province1">Province 1</option>
  <option value="province2">Province 2</option>
  <option value="province3">Province 3</option>
  <option value="province4">Province 4</option>
</select>

</div>
```